# Spotify support in Clementine broken 12.04 also purging doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, clementine, spotify, purge

I downloaded Clementine because I heard it had all sorts of connections to online music sources, including spotify.  I had it installed before but it was from the software center and didn't have spotify for some reason.  So I uninstall that and install it from the .deb on clementine's website.  I open it up put my login info in and install the plugin that it needs to support spotify.  I start playing some songs from my spotify and it works just fine.

But then I accidentally right clicked and selected one of my playlist to sync for offline listening, so I exited clementine to make it stop doing that.  Now whenever I try to play something on spotify on it, it just plays like the first second of the track then skips to the next track and then stops completely, also spotify results aren't showing up in the search bar even though I have spotify checked off to be in the searches.

I tried "complete removal" in synaptic and the purge command in the terminal on it to completely remove it so I could reinstall again and fix the problem, and the purge command does work on it, but when I reinstall it, it still remembers all my settings, like my logins and layout choices and songs in my playlist.  It's as if it doesn't realize that I even purged it.

I don't know how to fix it, there isn't a .clementine folder in the home folder for me to look at and I don't know why purging it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to remove your configurations files.

Paste this at terminal:

```
rm -R ~/.config/Clementine
```

Or open Nautilus, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and navigate to `~/.config`, find the folder `Clementine` and delete it.